# Read prev props: Too many renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want someone to confirm my intuition on below problem.

**My goal was to keep track (similar to [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)) of `props.personIdentId` and when it changed, to call         `setSuggestions([])`.**

Here is code:

```
function Identification(props) {
    let [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

    let prevPersonIdentId = useRef(null)
    let counter = useRef(0) // for logs

    // for accessing prev props
    useEffect(() => {
        prevPersonIdentId.current = props.personIdentId;
        console.log("Use effect", props.personIdentId, prevPersonIdentId.current, counter.current++)
    });


    // This props value has changed, act on it.
    if (props.personIdentId != prevPersonIdentId.current) {
        console.log("Props changed", props.personIdentId, prevPersonIdentId.current, counter.current++)

        setSuggestions([])
    }
```

But it was getting in an infinite loop as shown here:

[image]

My explanation why this happens is that: *initially when it detects the prop has changed from null to 3, it calls setSuggestions which schedules a re-render, then next re-render comes, but previous scheduled useEffect didn't have time to run, hence the prevPersonIdentId.current didn't get updated, and it again enters and passes the if condition which checks if prop changed and so on. Hence infinite loop.*

What confirms this intuition is that using this condition instead of old one, fixes the code:

```
 if (props.personIdentId != prevPersonIdentId.current) {
        prevPersonIdentId.current = props.personIdentId;
        setSuggestions([])
 }
```

Can someone confirm this or add more elaboration?

Comment: Unrelated to the purpose of your question, but you should check out the second parameter of the `useEffect` hook. If you do `useEffect(() => {}, [ props.personIdentId ])` then the function passed to the `useEffect` will only execute if the prop has changed. Meaning instead of a lot of logic to see if the prop has changed you can let the hook take care of that.

Comment: Your useEffect, you didn't pass your dependency list, [props.personIdentId]

Comment: @ApplePearPerson I know but that doesn't make any difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is what's happening:

1. On the first pass, `props.personId` is `undefined` and
   prevPersonIdentId.current is `null`. Note that `if (props.personIdentId !=
   prevPersonIdentId.current)` uses `!=` so `undefined` is coerced to
   `null` and you don't enter the if.
2. Another render occurs with the same conditions.
3. `props.personId` now changes, so you enter the if.
4. `setSuggestions([])` is called, triggering a re-render.
5. loop forever

Your `useEffect` is never invoked, because you keep updating your state and triggering re-renders before it has a chance to run.

If you want to respond to changes in the prop, rather than attempting to roll your own change-checking, you should just use `useEffect` with the value you want to respond to in a dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
       setSuggestions([])
 }, [props.personId] );
```

Comment: Your explanation matches my description too I guess. Yes for simple case if you want to trigger action when smth changes your approach seems more appropriate. I will accept it because I think it suffices in my case. Just in my approach I also had access to prev props. Other answer is also interesting.

Answer (score 2):

**useEffect - is asynchronous function!** 
And you put yours condition in synchronous part of component. Off course synchronous part runs before asynchronous.

Move condition to useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (personIdentId !== prevPersonIdentId.current) {
      prevPersonIdentId.current = personIdentId;
      console.log(
        "Use effect",
        personIdentId,
        prevPersonIdentId.current,
        counter.current++
      );
      setSuggestions([]);
    }
  });
```

It could be read as:
When mine component updates we check property personIdentId for changes and if yes we update ref to it's value and run some functions